# Java Spring jQuery ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have the following code

```
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    $.post("/valid",{emailadd: email},function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
```

on the server I have the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/valid", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Boolean checkValidEmail(@RequestParam("emailadd") String emailadd){
    return false;
}
```

Using firebug I can see that var email get the value but it skips past the alert function, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that data is empty? Try alert("Result: " + data);

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you see any response in firebug? Show it. Add error handler to your Ajax request. Check server logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is that you don't return any response. You are returning false or true, but doesn't this just stops the `checkValidEmail` method?

Not sure how this works within spring, but cant you render some text as output and see if that's outputted?

Comment: Thanks that worked with a String output, any idea why the boolean value didn't get returned?

Comment: it expected to be a string/html. you could check if the post worked by setting the header on the response within your spring code an then check the `statusText` in your callback. `function(data, statusText)` the text will be "timeout", "error", "notmodified", "success" or "parsererror". See jQuery doc's for more info about statusText

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to me that the call hasn't completed yet, so `data` won't be populated.  You will need to add a callback handler for `complete`

```
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        $.post("/valid",{emailadd: email},
            complete: function(data){
               alert(data);
            }
    });
```

Comment: complete isn't a function for `$.post` is it? I thought this was only for the `$.ajax` function

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. Maybe a stupid question but are you sure that the URL is right ? What about the webapp and the controller in the path ?

As a side note : `$("#email").val()` would be more jQuery friendly to get the email :)